# Magento 2.3.1 Product detail thumbnail images are not resizing into rectangle shape

Tags: magento2.3, product-images

[image]

After Magento Upgrade my product detail thumbnail images (which are square by default) are not resizing into rectangle images as it was working in Magento 2.2.6.

in view.xml

> ```
>         <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
>             <width>88</width>
>             <height>110</height>
>         </image>
> ```

I tried using: `<frame>false</frame>` but got no result.
& also in design- > Catalog module -> gallery.phtml file

```
  "thumbwidth": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width') ?>",
                "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
                ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
```

but nothing is working.

any suggestion why?

Comment: have you cleared the image cache?

Comment: yes from "flush Catalog image cache" but still no working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by making thumbnails square instead of a rectangle. I know it is not exactly what I wanted but solved for know. thank you,